# How to configure apache so html knows its aliases?

Tags: apache, url, apache2

I have 2 projects Symfony plus react.
They exist in 2 directories and react app uses Symfony app as api backend.

I tried to figure out the best way to connect it and I used Apache Alias
(/front -> my frontend directory because adding /api - backend dorectory broke backend )

Now..

Frontend app uses things like: .
I could add /front to url but i guess this isnlt right and my app shouldn't care what the aliases are.

What would be the best way to fix that?
Is there a way to configure it in apache or should I add some global variable before every url or is just putting front project inside backend project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basicly I bought a domain and created subdomain for backend and everything works well.